# How to get the ExceptionMessage in Angular

Tags: angular

Using this code, how do I error.ExceptionMessage?

It's exposed as I can see it in the console below but I get:

[ts] Property 'ExceptionMessage' does not exist on type 'HttpErrorResponse'

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
let errorMessage = "";

if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
  // Client-side error.
  errorMessage = `In ImageService - Client-side error: ${
    error.error.message
    }`;
} else {
  // Server-side error.
  errorMessage =
    `In ImageService - Server-side error status: ${
    error.status
    }\nMessage: ${error.message}` + `. Exception is: ${error.ExceptionMessage}`;
}

// Show a user-facing error message.
window.alert(
  "Contact the Administrator. Critical Error in ImageService. " +
  errorMessage
);
```

[image]

Comment: Try to `console.log` the `error` object. You will get properties of the object.

Comment: have you put ur code into try and catch block ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing it to this: ..`Exception is: ${error.error.ExceptionMessage}`..

The `HttpErrorResponse` you are inspecting has a `error` property that will contain the `ExceptionMessage`

You can have a look on the angular website for more information, Look for 'HttpErrorResponse'. ([link](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse#httperrorresponse))